# Is there a convenient way to remotely watch a user's screen in real time?

Tags: video, remote-access, video-streaming, conferencing

A friend of mine is going to have a video conference in Google Meet. At this conference she will be given some information in the conference chat and shown some documents. I'm not a participant of the conference, but she wants me to remotely watch her screen in real time during the conference, but in such a way that this can't be accidentally noticed by conference participants, who might ask her to share her screen at any time for the purpose of showing them some documents, or by people passing by her desktop or sitting nearby, who might have a look in her screen.

Is there a convenient way to do what she wants?

Our first idea was that she can have two video conferences at the same time, one in Google Meet with her conference participants and another one in Zoom with me so that she can share her screen with me via the Zoom conference, but the problem with this is that people might notice the Zoom conference on her screen. She wants to avoid that.

A few additional details: (1) she is prepared to give me any kind of remote access or control, so there are no trust issues between us whatsoever, (2) the sound is unimportant, so there is no need to transmit it or to ensure that I do not hear it, (3) our computers are Windows computers.

There may be a simple solution, but we are not very experienced users and humbly hope to get help here.

P.S. Although my friend's intention might seem somewhat ethically questionable, it actually isn't. The conference participants are not obligated or even expected to keep things confidential. She just doesn't want to make it obvious to other people that she is sharing her screen, so I'm asking to kindly focus on the technical aspect of my question.

---

UPDATE: In response to comments below, I'd like to emphasize that there's absolutely nothing illegal here. The conference is a meeting at which academic staff will discuss something with student representatives, who are expected to disseminate the information later as they deem fit, so there is no expectation of confidentiality whatsoever. My friend is a student representative, and the reason why she wants to share her screen with me in real time is that she wants me to have a look at documents, quickly analyze them, and help her quickly prepare a statement to be released shortly after the meeting. She doesn't want to show anyone that she has an "advisor" who helps her in such matters, and she wants to avoid being asked as to why she is sharing her screen.

Comment: a VNC server works perfectly for me in this case - I use `x11vnc` for linux but you can download any vnc server and turn off any notifications from connections. You'll need to be on the same network/LAN though

Comment: Frankly its unethical any way you stack it.

Comment: I am halfway through my answer that will definitely work for this case undoubtedly. Convince us that this isn't something illegal.
And why can't you just keep some screenshots and send her after meeting ends? If there's no trust issues, that should help. Honestly, no matter how much you put it in straightforward way it smells fishy.

Comment: @Sanu_012 : I just added an update at the end of my question to better explain the situation. If she keeps screenshots and sends me them after the meeting, I won't have enough time to analyze the documents. A statement has to be released shortly after the meeting.

Comment: Then why are you not in the meeting itself?

Comment: @Sanu_012 : Because I'm not a selected representative of the students.

Comment: Okay, I am adding the answer in next some mins. And thanks for the update, that helped.

Comment: @Sanu_012 : Thanks a lot. If your solution works, it will really help us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here is something that can definitely help you in this stealth mission. I really hope that you're not doing anything illegal and *I am not responsible for any harm caused.*

You both download and install an app called Teamviewer by going to this link:
[Download Teamviewer](https://download.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewer_Setup.exe). Both of you open it and then ask your friend to give you her ID and password shown on her screen:

[image]

Enter those credentials at your PC in the given 'Partner ID' box as shown above and after doing that click 'Connect to partner'. That's it. Now, you have got remote access to your friends PC and the screen will be visible to you.

(note: if you are still confused somewhere till now, or how to get started with TeamViewer; this video will help: [How to use TeamViewer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BUfIa6ru30))

But even after this, the TeamViewer icon will still be visible on your friend's taskbar. If you are not bothered about this, you are good to go to the meeting. To hide it further from taskbar, tell her to go to `Extras` as highlighted here:

[image]

Then ask her to go to `Advanced>Show advanced options`:

[image]

A menu will show up. Ask her to 'check' the `Close to tray` menu as shown and click `OK`:

[image]

Now, ask her to close her TeamViewer normally. It will be not be closed but will minimize to system tray and you can still watch her screen on your PC.

That is it. I hope this helps. If you still face any problem, revert back to me in the comment section. Tell me how it does :)

PS. Bear with me for the pictures :(

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that, I could've used other built-in options, but having known your requirements and to make this as stealth as possible, I relied upon this method.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to be a great solution. We'll now try it to check how it works :)

Comment: And if you find that hiding teamviewer from taskbar thing difficult, revert back in the comments. I have a shortcut for that :)

Comment: The solution is perfect :) We tested it, and it works well, so we will use it. 'When we tested the solution, we initially did not know how to get rid of the Team Viewer panel, but then found that it can be simply dragged by the mouse to beneath the screen :)

Comment: Okay. Sounds great. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 has a "Quick Assist" function that allows access to another user's screen, either full control or view screen. I use this to help friends and neighbors who want to know they aren't giving me uncontrolled access to their machines without installing any extra tools.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026516/windows-solve-pc-problems-remote-connection-quick-assist